# How to generate an empty bpm:comment box in Alfresco Activiti Workflow Task?

Tags: java, workflow, alfresco, activiti, business-process-management

I'm developing a custom workflow, where I would like comments from the previous task to be shown in the task form for the next task. To achieve this, I have a custom 'previous comment' text property which is rendered as a read-only text area. In each task I also have a bpm:comment field for the user to add their comments when they complete the task (I need to use bpm:comment because otherwise the comments are not saved in the workflow history table).

In my workflow process, I set the 'previous comment' property to the value of the bpm:comment from the previous task, which works fine. However, on the next task, the bpm:comment field is shown containing the comment from the start task. I've attached an image displaying this (in this case, "Admin comments" is the first comment inputted when the workflow is started). I've also added my files. What I want to change, is for the bpm:comment field to be rendered with an empty text box, but I can't figure out how to do this. Any suggestions?

Marcus

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fBxS.png

Comment: Workflow Model: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By5ruty8M4IleThyMVVYUWNwZDQ/view?usp=sharing

Share-config-custom.xml:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By5ruty8M4IlREpoTk5MS2F3U0U

Process Definition File:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By5ruty8M4IlUnl3XzljLWk3MDQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help from Vikash, I've figured out how to do this. After setting the value of the previous comment variable, I set the value of bpm_comment to null, which clears the field in the task form but maintains the comment in the workflow history

Answer (score 0):

please try by appending your comments to previous comments

ex:

```
var comment = ((execution.getVariable("vorwf_prevComment") !=null)?execution.getVariable("vorwf_prevComment"):"") +"\n<p>"+person.properties.userName+":</p>"+task.getVariableLocal('bpm_comment');

execution.setVariable("vorwf_prevComment",comment);
```

and after that set `bpm_comment` property to null

hope this will help you.

It is displaying in comment box because of by default while submitting the form `bpm_comment` property is set with the textbox's value of which you have entered.
So set `bpm_comment` to null.

Comment: Hi vikash, 
I tried this method but I was getting a script error from Alfresco which I couldn't solve. However, setting bpm_comment to null, after setting the value of vorwf:prevComment, has solved the problem, while maintaining the comments field in the workflow history. Thank you

Comment: Are able to do what you want?